# Using multiple ObjectContexts in Entity Framework 4 with the repository/uow pattern

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, poco

i am using EF4 and StructureMap in an asp.net web application. I am using the repository/unit of work patterns as [detailed in this post](http://devtalk.dk/2009/06/09/Entity+Framework+40+Beta+1+POCO+ObjectSet+Repository+And+UnitOfWork.aspx). In the code, there is a line that delegates the setup of an ObjectContext in global.asax.

```
EntityUnitOfWorkFactory.SetObjectContext(() => new MyObjectContext());
```

On the web page code-behind, you can create a generic repository interface like so ...

```
IRepository<MyPocoObject> ds = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<MyPocoObject>>();
```

My question is what is a good approach to refactoring this code so that I can use more than one ObjectContext and differentiate between them in the code-behind? Basically i have two databases/entity models in my application and need to query them both on the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Unit of Work is used to manage persistence across *multiple repositories*, not *multiple object contexts*.

You're not going to be able to persist changes across multiple contexts using a unit of work, as the UoW is simply implemented as a wrapper for a ObjectContext. Therefore, you'll need **two** unit of works.

Overall, things are going to get messy. You're going to have two OCs newed up and disposed each HTTP request, not to mention transaction management is going to be a nightmare.

**Must** you have two ObjectContexts? What is the reasoning for this? If it's for scalability, don't bother; it's going to be too painful for other things like your repository, unit of work and http scope management.

It's hard to provide good advice without seeing how you have your repositories set up.

Try creating wrapper classes for each object context, each implementing IUnitOfWork and a secondary unique interface (IEfSqlContext1, etc which represents one of your models/contexts).

Then you can inject whichever context you want.

As I said though, try and avoid having two EDMX/Contexts. It's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Sometimes it is good to have two EDMX + contexts. I don't know why, but designer doesn't like some features like defining queries and it permanently deletes my changes during update from database. So I ended up with one edmx for common mapping and one edmx for special features. But the difference is that my second object context is readonly = no need for UoW.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - interesting approach. Maybe you should add an answer?

Comment: @Ladislav: Interesting. Perhaps you should write down a question that state the problems you are having. There must be a better way.

Comment: thanks for your reply - unfortunately i do need 2 objectcontexts as i am dealing with legacy databases. However your answer did help in terms of thinking it through again. The unit of work in the original post handles persistance across an httprequest and within that you can have more than one objectcontext. I adapted the code so that the unit of work handles a List<ObjectContext>.